# Logout from Facebook after sharing [Xamarin.Android]

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin

Is there any way to logout from facebook after sharing? I use code below:

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().Build();

ShareDialog sharedialog = new ShareDialog(this);

sharedialog.Show(linkContent);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Android Facebook SDK, you can use the:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

As per the documentation found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/

Comment: This is a good approach, but this method logs out from every device you've logged in. How can you log out only from one device? In this case how to log out only from xamarin android application?